# Is the stack-allocated variable that contains the overflowed buffer also called a buffer?

Tags: c++

I would just like to clarify if the stack-allocated variable that contains the overflow is also called a buffer? Or it refers to the areas of the memory like text segment, heap segment or stack segment?

For example...

```
void func(char* arg3)
{
    char buf[5];
    strcpy(buf, arg3);
}

int main()
{
    char *display = "HelloWorld";
    func (display); //buffer overflow since HelloWorld consists of 10 characters
                    // while the buffer is only 5...
}
```

Seeking the name of the variable or the term use to denote the variable that contains the overflowed buffer.

Comment: What do you mean by "stack-allocated variable that contains the overflow" ?

Comment: For example...                                                                                              char buf[5]; strcpy(buf, arg3)...} int main() { char *display = "HelloWorld"; func (display);...{ //buffer overflow since HelloWorld is consist of 10 characters while the buffer is only 5...The name of the variable or the term use to denote the variable that contains the overflowed buffer.

Comment: Edit your question if you have relevant information, don't put it in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute...

```
char buf[5];
strcpy(buf, arg3);
```

...with `arg3` pointing to a longer string, the program may attempt to write to memory after the stack memory reserved for `buf`, and that causes *undefined behaviour*.  Your program can't be expected to work properly, and may corrupt data, output garbage, hang, crash etc..

> I would just like to clarify if the stack-allocated variable that contains the overflow is also called a buffer?

The stack-allocated variable - namely `buf` - does not even attempt to "contain" the "overflow".  The invalid code corrupts memory, very likely memory on the stack, though if your stack happens to be almost full you might even try to write past the end of the stack.  `buf` itself can reasonably be deemed a `buffer`.

> Or it refers to the areas of the memory like text segment, heap segment or stack segment?

Not sure what you're guessing at here.  `buf` is on the stack, as is the pointer `display` (if it's not optimised away), while the characters `"HelloWorld\0"` will likely be in a read-only data segment (traditionally `rodata` segment or `.rodata`).

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer:

> a data buffer (or just buffer) is a region of a physical memory
>   storage used to temporarily store data while it is being moved from
>   one place to another.

It has nothing to do with stack/heap etc.
And an overflow doesn´t swallow the other variables purpose